# A faster strptime?

Tags: python, performance, datetime, strptime

I have code which reads vast numbers of dates in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. Parsing all these dates, so that it can add one, two, or three days then write back in the same format is slowing things down quite considerably.

```
 3214657   14.330    0.000  103.698    0.000 trade.py:56(effective)
 3218418   34.757    0.000   66.155    0.000 _strptime.py:295(_strptime)

 day = datetime.datetime.strptime(endofdaydate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Any suggestions how to speed it up a bit (or a lot)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Python 3.7+: `fromisoformat()`

Since Python 3.7, the `datetime` class has a method `fromisoformat`. It should be noted that this can also be applied to this question:

#### Performance vs. `strptime()`

Explicit string slicing may give you about a 9x increase in performance compared to normal `strptime`, but you can get about a **90x increase with the built-in `fromisoformat` method!**

```
%timeit isofmt(datelist)
569 µs ± 8.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit slice2int(datelist)
5.51 ms ± 48.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit normalstrptime(datelist)
52.1 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
base, n = datetime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 420001), 10000
datelist = [(base + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in range(n)]

def isofmt(l):
    return list(map(datetime.fromisoformat, l))
    
def slice2int(l):   
    def slicer(t):
        return datetime(int(t[:4]), int(t[5:7]), int(t[8:10]))
    return list(map(slicer, l))

def normalstrptime(l):
    return [datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d') for t in l]
    
print(isofmt(datelist[0:1]))
print(slice2int(datelist[0:1]))
print(normalstrptime(datelist[0:1]))

# [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
# [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
# [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
```

---

Python 3.8.3rc1 x64 / Win10

Comment: But fromisoformat is "this does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it is only intended as the inverse operation of datetime.isoformat()" from https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

So dates like "2020-08-24T00:00:00.00+00:00" do not work

Comment: @visch well, not providing a *proper* ISO format parser (and formatter) in the standard library of a full-featured language like Python is pretty poor if you ask me (we have 3.10 now!). **But** why should this prevent you from using the features that do exist to your full advantage?

Comment: I'd love to use the function, but I hit at least one case (the one in the last comment) that doesn't work (even though I'm pretty sure it's a valid iso 8601 datetime). I ended up going with https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601

Comment: @visch Python's ISO format parser has been extended in Python 3.11, for example "2020-08-24T00:00:00.00+00:00" is now parsed correctly.

Answer (score 40):

Is factor 7 lot enough?

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d').date()       # 8.87us

datetime.date(*map(int, a.split('-')))                 # 1.28us
```

**EDIT:** great idea with explicit slicing:

```
datetime.date(int(a[:4]), int(a[5:7]), int(a[8:10]))   # 1.06us
```

that makes factor 8.

Comment: In context: strptime = 128s, this = 61s, and for 55s be explicit: `datetime.date(int(a[:4]), int(a[5:7]), int(a[8:10]))`.  Now to replace the strftime and potentially prune another 10s... thx.

Answer (score 0):

For an ISO-formatted timezone-free string, eg.: `"2021-01-04T14:30:03.123"`:

```py
datetime.datetime(int(d[:4]), int(d[5:7]), int(d[8:10]), int(d[11:13]), int(d[14:16]), int(d[17:19]), int(d[20:]))
```

Seems to run faster than `strptime()`.

Comment: *Seems* to run faster? How did you benchmark?

Comment: Honestly, I remember reading about it somewhere at the time and the results that I got when testing it out suggested that indeed this ran even faster. I now tried finding that resource again, and I couldn't, my bad. I also went back to my old code - parsing some csv date strings - and tried some tests to verify this claim, but unfortunately couldn't confirm this. So I've edited this post to remove the statement about running faster than `fromisoformat()`. Thanks for pointing it out 