# How to improve the efficiency of time.strptime in Python?

Tags: python, performance, python-module

I use Spyder's profiler to run a python script, which handles 700000 lines of data,
and the `time.strptime` function takes more than **60s**(the built-in function `sort` only takes 11s).

How should I improve its efficiency? Is there any effective module for time manipulation?

The core code snippet is here:

```
data = []
fr = open('big_data_out.txt')
for line in fr.readlines():
    curLine = line.strip().split(',')
    curLine[2] = time.strptime( curLine[2], '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
    curLine[5] = time.strptime( curLine[5], '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
#    print curLine
    data.append(curLine)

data.sort(key = lambda l:( l[2], l[5], l[7]) )
#print data

result = []
for itm in data:
    if itm[2] >= start_time and itm[5] <= end_time and itm[1] == cameraID1 and itm[4] == cameraID2:
        result.append(itm)
```

Comment: Are there many similar times?  Or are most of the times unique?

Comment: Are you interested in `data`, or just `result`? You might be able to skip some of the calls to `strptime()` if you move the if statements inside your `for line` loop and skip lines that don’t match the camera ID, or where you find an out-of-bounds date in the first data. That’s probably more memory efficient as well.

Comment: You may also want to look at whether `datetime.datetime.strptime()` is any better. I believe it does something very similar, but it might have a performance edge. I don’t know.

Comment: There is no need to use `.readlines()`. You are building a list of 700000 lines for no reason. You should also use `with` to open your files or at least close them. You can also use the csv module which will create the rows for you splitting on `,`.

Comment: I just checked datetime.strptime(), and performance is basically the same.

Comment: @alexwlchan I just advance the if statement to the first loop, and it did great work to improve the performance. Thanks for your ardent advice.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for your advice, I merge the two loops into one and the time cost has been reduced to less than 2s.

Comment: If you were able to get it faster, post your improved code as an answer, with some comments about what you changed – it will help other people who come across this question. (Self-answering is totally okay here, and encouraged.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer given here:
[A faster strptime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime)

```
>>> timeit.timeit("time.strptime(\"2015-02-04 04:05:12\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\")", setup="import time")
17.206257617290248
>>> timeit.timeit("datetime.datetime(*map(int, \"2015-02-04 04:05:12\".replace(\":\", \"-\").replace(\" \", \"-\").split(\"-\")))", setup="import datetime")
4.687687893159023
```

Comment: Well, I think the key point is that you use the `map` function instead of a string. I think `strptime` function cost lots of time while handling the string.