# Is there a faster alternative to Python's strftime?

Tags: python, strftime

I'm processing hundreds of thousands of dates in Python and noticing that the `strftime` function is pretty slow.

I used timeit to check and it tells me that it takes roughly 0.004 which is fine for a small number but becomes problematic for processing a couple thousand for example.

```
print(min(timeit.Timer("now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')", setup=setup).repeat(7,1000))
```

Is there any faster alternative?

Comment: I don't think so. You could go for caching if the entries repeat themselves, or splittingg it into threads (which is very error-prone however).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime this may help.

Comment: @AjaySingh: That question is about `strptime`, the string-to-timestamp function.  This question is about `strftime`, the timestamp-to-string function.

Comment: @gonczor Splitting into threads will not help CPU-bound tasks in most implementations of Python since there is typically a global lock that prevents threads from running concurrently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have a rigid format you can just access directly the fields of the `datetime` object and use Python string formatting to construct the required string:

```
'{:02d}/{:02d}/{}'.format(now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

In Python 3 this is about 4 times faster than `strftime()`. It's also faster in Python 2, about 2-3 times as fast.

Faster again in Python 3 is the "old" style string interpolation:

```
'%02d/%02d/%d' % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
```

about 5 times faster, but I've found this one to be slower for Python 2.

Another option, but only 1.5 times faster, is to use [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) instead of `datetime.strftime()`:

```
time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', now.timetuple())
```

---

Finally, how are you constructing the `datetime` object to begin with? If you are converting strings to `datetime` (with `strptime()` for example), it might be faster to convert the incoming string version to the outgoing one using string slicing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, trying these out now. Essentially I have a datetime object and would like to output something like 'Thursday 10th Dec at 10:44AM'. The datetime comes directly from the db.

Comment: Mapping the day of week to the day name is more difficult and will slow down these alternative methods. Ditto for month name. Assuming that you do not actually need a `datetime` object, perhaps you can select the date from the database as a string in the required format? (or you could do both: get a `datetime` _and_ a string representation of it)

Comment: Right so I realised I couldn't do that as there's some additional timezone conversion that happens after the db call. Instead of meddling with that I opted with your suggestion of using the `time.strftime` instead which is pretty impressive and is a sufficient performance improvement and frankly works well :). Appreciate your help!

Comment: Don't suppose you know any other techniques? Just curious if there's anything else that could result in some quick wins.

Comment: The best way, probably, is to do the work in the database if you can. That depends on the database in use - which one? What is the timezone conversion? Is it converting UTC to local time? Other than that I don't know of any faster way to produce the output string from a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is marginally faster on my box (python 2.7.x)

```
def fmt(date):
    return "%02d/%02d/%d" % (date.month, date.day, date.year)
```