# What is the quickest way to increment date string YYYY-MM-DD in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

In Pandas, I am using dates with string format `YYYY-MM-DD` 
What is the quickest way to increment the date with the result in `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

```
d1 = '2018-02-10'
```

I want to increment it by 1 and get the result back as a string:

```
d1_inc = '2018-02-11'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "quick"? What have you tried so far? Please share some code. Make sure to clearify the question so that it is not oppinion based

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Pure Python

You can use the `datetime` module, part of the standard library. There are 3 steps:

1. Convert string to `datetime` object via `strptime`.
2. Add a day via `timedelta`.
3. Convert resulting `datetime` object back to string via `strftime`.

Here's a demo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = '2017-05-15'
res = (datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(res)    
# 2017-05-16
```

#### Pandas

The equivalent steps can be performed using 3rd party Pandas:

```
x = '2017-05-15'

# choose some combination of below methods
res = (pd.Timestamp(x) + pd.DateOffset(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
res = (pd.to_datetime(x) + pd.Timedelta('1 day')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(res)
# 2017-05-16
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), `pd.TimeDelta` and `strftime`:

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
(pd.to_datetime(<your series or column>, format=fmt) + pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.strftime(date_format=fmt)
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-04-02', '2017-04-23']})
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
>>> (pd.to_datetime(df.date, format=fmt) + pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.strftime(date_format=fmt)
0    2017-04-03
1    2017-04-24
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform arithmetic operations with datetime and timedelta objects.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime(year=2018, month=3, day=1)
t = timedelta(days=1)

d + t
# datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 2, 0, 0)

d + t + t
# datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 3, 0, 0)

for i in range(30):
    d += 1

print(d)
# datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this

```
date = datetime.date(2015,5,15)
date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by quickest. I'm assuming you mean the quickest way to program this, not the shortest program execution time (which might be relevant when you're doing lots of these).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

original_date = '2018-5-15'

print('The original date is {}, the date one day later is: {}'.
       format(original_date, (datetime.strptime(original_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + 
       timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Step by step version:

Create a datetime object from the string, note the string that shows python the formatting (see [the documentation for more information](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior))

```
dt = datetime.strptime(original_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Add a day

```
dt += timedelta(days=1)
```

Reformat it back to the requested string

```
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

That's all!

Comment: I meant the quickest execution time.

Comment: Ah cool, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime) for some ideas on how to speed up strp/ftime. Also parallelization will help a great deal (if you're not doing anything intrinsically serial with the data).

Depending on your scope it might be worth investigating avoiding date/datetime objects altogether. And just hardcode the whole thing, including leap years.