# Faster datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, byte, python-datetime

Trying to get the `unixtimestamp` from millions of `bytes` objects

Using this

```
import datetime 
dt_bytes = b'2019-05-23 09:37:56.362965'
#fmt = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
dt_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_bytes.decode('utf-8'), fmt)
unix_ts = dt_ts.timestamp()
```

works perfect:

```
In [82]: unix_ts                                                                                                             
Out[82]: 1558604276.362965
```

But the `decode('utf-8')` is cutting the flow rate in half (from 38k/sec to 20k/sec).

So is there a way to **get the unixtimestamp from a `bytes` input instead of a `str` input?**

**__UPDATE:__**

I found out that the bottleneck is `datetime.datetime.strptime(..)`, so I switched to `np.datetime64` ([see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61644438/940592))

**__UPDATE 2:__** 
Check the accepted answer below to get a good performance benchmark of different approaches.

Comment: Try `decode('ascii')` and see if that's faster.  If the input only contains dates and times, it shouldn't need the full Unicode character set.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sadly this is  not the case - The runtimes are around equal (19.850 per second).

Comment: Ok I will delete the question, because `dt_bytes.decode('ascii')` is demanding almost no runtime. The `datetime.datetime.strptime(..)` method **slows** it down - not the `decode`

Comment: I've been wracking my brain for a faster way to convert to string and I can't think of one. The best I could come up with is `''.join(chr(b) for b in dt_bytes)` but I doubt that will be faster.

Comment: You could try `dateutil` to parse the date, it might be faster.

Comment: check out [A faster strptime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime) - explicit conversion of parts of the string to int might look ugly but if you have a fixed string format coming in, this is much faster than `strptime`. Won't get around decoding though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first assume you have strings in ISO format, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f', in a `list` (let's also not consider decoding from byte array for now):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
base, n = datetime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 420001), 1000
datelist = [(base + timedelta(days=i)).isoformat(' ') for i in range(n)]
# datelist
# ['2000-01-01 01:02:03.420001'
# ...
# '2002-09-26 01:02:03.420001']
```

---

***from string to datetime object***

Let's define some functions that parse string to `datetime`, using different methods:

```
import re
import numpy as np

def strp_isostr(l):
    return list(map(datetime.fromisoformat, l))

def isostr_to_nparr(l):
    return np.array(l, dtype=np.datetime64)

def split_isostr(l):
    def splitter(s):
        tmp = s.split(' ')
        tmp = tmp[0].split('-') + [tmp[1]]
        tmp = tmp[:3] + tmp[3].split(':')
        tmp = tmp[:5] + tmp[5].split('.')
        return datetime(*map(int, tmp))
    return list(map(splitter, l))

def resplit_isostr(l):
    # return list(map(lambda s: datetime(*map(int, re.split('T|-|\:|\.', s))), l))
    return [datetime(*map(int, re.split('\ |-|\:|\.', s))) for s in l]

def full_stptime(l):
    # return list(map(lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'), l))
    return [datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for s in l]
```

If I run `%timeit` in the IPython console for these functions on my machine, I get

```
%timeit strp_isostr(datelist)
98.2 µs ± 766 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit isostr_to_nparr(datelist)
1.49 ms ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit split_isostr(datelist)
3.02 ms ± 236 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit resplit_isostr(datelist)
3.8 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit full_stptime(datelist)
16.7 ms ± 780 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So we can conclude that **the built-in `datetime.fromisoformat` is by far the fastest option** for the 1000-element input. However, this assumes you want a `list` to work with. In case you need an `np.array` of `datetime64` anyway, going straight to that seems like the best option.

---

***third party option: ciso8601***

If you're able to install additional packages, `ciso8601` is worth a look:

```
import ciso8601
def ciso(l):
    return list(map(ciso8601.parse_datetime, l))

%timeit ciso(datelist)
138 µs ± 1.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

***from datetime object to seconds since the epoch***

Looking at the conversion from `datetime` object to POSIX timestamp, using the most obvious `datetime.timestamp` method seems to be the most efficient:

```
import time
def dt_ts(l):
    return list(map(datetime.timestamp, l))

def timetup(l):
    return list(map(time.mktime, map(datetime.timetuple, l)))

%timeit dt_ts(strp_isostr(datelist))
572 µs ± 4.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit timetup(strp_isostr(datelist))
1.44 ms ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Wow - Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: @gies0r, glad if it helps! I just noticed I forgot to include the conversion to POSIX timestamp, that you had in mind in your question. Sorry for that ;-) Will have a look into this as well when I have the time.

Comment: @gies0r: made an edit to include the conversion to POSIX timestamp.

Comment: It is a very complete answer - More than one could expect. Thank you again! Hopefully other people will benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am moving to `numpy.datetime64` because it has less delay than `datetime.strptime`

```
import numpy as np

# This is the format np.datetime64 needs:
#np.datetime64('2002-06-28T01:00:00.000000000+0100')

dt_bytes = b'2019-05-23 09:37:56.362965'
#dt_bytes_for_np = dt_bytes.split(b' ')[0] + b'T' + dt_bytes.split(b' ')[1]
dt_bytes_for_np = dt_bytes.replace(b' ', b'T')
ts = np.datetime64(dt_bytes_for_np)
```

And getting the unixtimestamp (this adds a bit of latency, but still way better than `datetime.strptime`:

```
ts.astype('datetime64[ns]').astype('float') / 1000000000
1558604276.362965
```

Comment: did you run a `%timeit`?

Comment: Doing it right now. The `ts = np.datetime64(dt_bytes_for_np)` is very fast! The `astype` is getting it down from 38k/sec to 30k/sec.

Comment: Why are you running `split` twice? It seems like the fastest way would be to use `dt_bytes.replace(b' ', b'T')`.

Comment: Good catch. Played around with different date-formats. Adapted.