# Extract Date-Month_year from utc format string python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a using below code to extract date-month-year from the string of a date however it is giving me

```
time data '2020-05-11T04:47:54.530000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

error, can anyone help?

```
from datetime import datetime
cr_date="2020-05-11T04:47:54.530000"
datetime.strptime(cr_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Replace the space with `T` in the format

Comment: this clearly is a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compatible string, so if you're on Python 3.7 or higher, use the built-ins, see my answer below. `fromisoformat` is also much faster than `strptime`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your own code just add `T` see the following:

```py
    from datetime import datetime
    cr_date="2020-05-11T04:47:54.530000"

    date_object = datetime.strptime(cr_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Another way to solve this is using `regex` ,

```py
    import re
    from datetime import datetime

    cr_date="2020-05-11T04:47:54.530000"
    match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', cr_date)
    date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Comment: why so complicated and use `regex`? why not just `split` on 'T'? ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes sorry if regex is to complex for you but its another approach to solve the issue.

Comment: [Python PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): Simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Python 3.7 or higher, use `fromisoformat`:

```
from datetime import datetime
cr_date="2020-05-11T04:47:54.530000"

datetime.fromisoformat(cr_date)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 4, 47, 54, 530000)
```

you can `strftime` that however you want now, e.g.

```
datetime.fromisoformat(cr_date).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
# '05/11/2020'
```