# Python - convert string type to datetime type

Tags: python, datetime

I have a two variables that i want to compare. When printed, this is what they look like:

```
2020-05-20 13:01:30
2020-05-20 14:49:03
```

However, one is a string type, and the other a datetime type.
If I want to convert the string one into date type so I can compare them, is the only way to use `strptime`? Because this seems a little redundant to me, since the string already has the exact format I want it to have. Basically, is there a function that does the same as `strptime`, but without re-formating it? As you can imagine, googling this problem is impossible, as all I'm getting is people trying to format any kind of string into datetime, so all the answers are just pointing at `strptime`.

Comment: You need to change the data type since comparison is not defined for str vs datetime types.  Another option you have is to convert datetime into str by `str` function, which is applied under the hood when you print them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: no, the accepted answer to this question is exactly what i did not want to do, and the second best answer requires a third party module, i already got a better answer here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you work with Python 3.7+, for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compatible strings, use [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) as this is considerably more efficient than `strptime` or dateutil's `parser`. Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-05-20 13:01:30')
print(repr(dtobj))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 13, 1, 30)
```

You can find a benchmark vs. `strptime` etc. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `parser` provided by `dateutil`

```py
from dateutil import parser

date_object = parser.parse("2020-05-20 13:01:30")

print(repr(date_object))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 13, 1, 30)

print(type(date_object)) 
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>

print(date_object)  
# 2020-05-20 13:01:30
```

From the docs:

> This module offers a generic date/time string parser which is able to parse most known formats to represent a date and/or time.

Documentation: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Comment: works too, but since datetime already does the job ill rather use that instead of having to import a module just for this, but thanks!

Comment: Yeah makes sense, but this parser supports many other formats. So you are not restricted with just the ISO format.

Comment: for ISO format, you probably want to use [isoparse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) since more efficient than the standard parser.