# Covert datetime64[ns, UTC] to datetime64 python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column with datetime UTC date

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

Can someone help me to convert it to just datetime64 for eg:

```
2020-01-01
```

Comment: Could you share some more details, e.g. how do you read this column in your python code? Is that a string or some builtin db date type? what is your database system?

Comment: if you use pandas (this seems to be the case) you can change it like that: df.dates.apply(lambda x: x.date())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use pandas (this seems to be the case) you can change it like that:

```
df.dates.apply(lambda x: x.date()) # where dates is your datetime column
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `datetime` package with Python 3.2+.

```
import datetime
a='2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00'
print (datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: you can use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()` here - it is [much more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418) ;-)

Comment: Ah. Python 3.7+! My Python is clearly out of date :) Thanks!

Comment: sure, I always forget the "python3.7+" tag... sorry ;-)