# Why datetime.datetime.strptime raises ValueError although the format is valid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I get this date string format from the database and I need to convert it to datetime object in order to do subtraction.

```
'from': '2020-06-24T10:12:00.692+00:00'
```

I've tried this formatting, but that does not work.

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
```

Is that string even convertible in python?

Update:
That's the strptime I run

```
datetime_obj1= datetime.strptime(row['from'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

The error I get

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7798f7219c52> in <module>
     23 for row in list_of_events:
     24     print(row['id'])
---> 25     datetime_obj1= datetime.strptime(row['from'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
     26     print(datetime_obj1)
     27     #print(row['from']-row['to'])

/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    563     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    564     format string."""
--> 565     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    566     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    567     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    360     if not found:
    361         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 362                          (data_string, format))
    363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '2020-06-24T10:12:00.692+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

Comment: on Python 3.7+, use `datetime.fromisoformat('2020-06-24T10:12:00.692+00:00')` - by the way, your format code for `strptime` also works fine for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue about parsing RFC 3339 dates and times at [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue15873) and it is resolved on python3.7.

So `%z` is not supported for < [python3.7](/questions/tagged/python3.7).

Comment: nice, wasn't aware of that one yet... I wonder why the Z character can be parsed by `%z` in strptime but not `fromisoformat()`... (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date))

Answer (score 2):

Without some actual code it's hard to say, where your mistake was.

The date format you suggested works just fine...

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("2020-06-24T10:12:00.692+00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 10, 12, 0, 692000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: `fromisoformat` is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418) :)

Answer (score 1):

on older Python versions, you should be able to make use of `dateutil`'s parser:

```
from dateutil import parser

s = '2020-06-24T10:12:00.692+00:00'

dtobj = parser.isoparse(s)
# - or -
# dtobj = parser.parse(s)

# dtobj
# datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 10, 12, 0, 692000, tzinfo=tzutc())
```