# Convert String date to long in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have data frame which has a column full of date-time of format `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSS.000Z`

For example, `2019-06-17T19:17:45.000Z`. I want to convert this to long type (unix epoch time) in python.

How to do that?

Thanks!

(How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date? This question is abut parsing the string. I want to do a conversion and hence it is different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use module time:

```
import calendar
import time
calendar.timegm(time.strptime('2019-06-17T19:17:45.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
```

Output: 1560799065

Comment: You should also be able to use %z in the format string, `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'`, to parse the Z character. However, to make use of the result, you'll have to use `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

Answer (score 1):

using `datetime` module, `fromisoformat` (most likely [fastest option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418)) to parse the string and `timestamp()` to get POSIX seconds since the epoch:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = '2019-06-17T19:17:45.000Z'
ts = datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace('Z', '+00:00')).timestamp()
#  1560799065.0
```

or `strptime` with appropriate format code:

```
ts = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').timestamp()
```

...or `dateutil`'s parser.parse (slower but even more convenient):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
ts = parse(s).timestamp()
```

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat' I get this error while trying out the fastest option.

Comment: @yahooo: are you sure your imports are correct? in the example, I only import the `datetime` class, not the whole datetime module

Comment: yes I used the same imports that you gave. I copied those 3 lines into my notebook and it gave me this error. The second option to use parser.parse works correctly.

Comment: @yahooo: btw. which Python version are you using? fromisoformat is Python 3.7+  ;-)

Comment: Ah. Maybe thats the reason why. I am using python version 3.6.10.

Comment: @yahooo: then maybe you can use `datetime.strptime`, see my edit of the answer.