# time data '2020-07-09T00:00:00+05:30' does not match format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am getting this error time data `2020-07-09T00:00:00+05:30` does not match format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` please help

Comment: Please give us the minimal amount of your code needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: use `datetime.fromisoformat('2020-07-09T00:00:00+05:30')`. `“yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ”` is not a valid format string; check out https://strftime.org/.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case it would help if you post a [mre] and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63030181/10197418

Answer (score 1):

```
datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-07-09T00:00:00+05:30')
```

Comment: i need this date 2020-07-09T00:00:00+05:30 format