# Python3 Converting a string into datetime with zulu object in

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, iso

Can't convert a string into a DateTime object in Python3.8.5.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> x = "2020-06-27T16:03:00+0000"
```

Variations of formats I have tried after referencing:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z'
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.f%z'
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%z'
```

I tried a bunch of other combinations that did not make a lot of sense.
I need the Zulu time added as my code deals with sorting a bunch of events from international tracking.

Everything I've seen has been about Python2.7 having issues with Zulu time formats.

**SOLVED**:
Zulu time includes the `+` and the `-`
therefore

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

is the correct format.
Will answer when I can for a brief answer for others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 2):

The `+` sign is part of the timezone offset, so the format string doesn't need to contain `+` sign

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> x = "2020-06-27T16:03:00+0000"
>>>
>>> datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 27, 16, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dateutil` library

```
In [15]: from dateutil import parser

In [16]: x = "2020-06-27T16:03:00+0000"

In [17]: parser.parse(x)
Out[17]: datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 27, 16, 3, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.7+, you could also use `fromisoformat`. It requires a `str.replace` but might be [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime).

```
from datetime import datetime
x = "2020-06-27T16:03:00+0000"
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(x.replace('+0000', '+00:00'))
print(repr(dt))
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 27, 16, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```