# strptime command works in jupyter, but not in pycharm

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have the statements:

```
v  = datetime.strptime('2020-07-08T09:00:01+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(v)
```

The part that doesn't work is the timezone. I know this because it works find if I don't use the timezone.

```
v  = datetime.strptime('2020-07-08T09:00:01', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

This works as I expect in Jupyter; however, I can't get it to work in PyCharm.
PyCharm configured to use a VE.  Not using the same version of python.

It returns the error:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-07-08T09:00:01+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

In PyCharm console:

```
print (sys.version_info)
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

In Jupiter

```
print (sys.version_info)
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Is there some other way to do this? A different code?  Am I missing something?

Comment: In Python 3.7, `.strptime()` gained the ability to ignore that colon in the middle of the UTC offset. Previous versions would require the field to be written as `+0000`.

Comment: That's it!  So I guess the fix is I manually remove that colon. thanks

Comment: With Py3.7+, you should be able to use `fromisoformat` instead of `strptime` ([a bit more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime)).