# Convert 2020-09-01T00:00:00-05:00 timestamp to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: python, datetime

Hi I am trying to convert the following time format

```
2020-08-28T13:42:00.298363-05:00
```

to

```
28-Sept-2020
```

I am using the following code but it does not work.

```
from datetime import datetime
 
start_time = "2020-08-28T13:42:00.298363-05:00"
start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%f.%-s-%z)
    print(start_period_obj)
```

and the output is

```
File "time conveter.py", line 19
    start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%f.%-s-%z)
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: I have added an answer if it works please check mark and upvote the answer.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Please explain the negative vote to me? did anyone even try running the code?

Comment: @Grayrigel I did not vote on your post.

Comment: @Grayrigel I upvoted you, though I didn't see it changed. I don't know why it didn't change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
 
start_time = "2020-08-28T13:42:00.298363-05:00"

#removing the time information since, you don't want in the final output anyway
start_time  = start_time.split('T')[0]
start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%d")
start_period_obj = start_period_obj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
print(start_period_obj)
```

Or this one liner:

```
start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(start_time.split('T')[0], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
print(start_period_obj)
```

**Output**:

```
'28-Aug-2020'
```

Comment: this is a one-liner (Python 3.7)... `datetime.fromisoformat("2020-08-28T13:42:00.298363-05:00").strftime("%d-%b-%Y")`

Comment: Thanks. well, I didn't know about it. Added one line solution using  `strptime` and `strftime` probably slower but works.

Comment: ok my comment might have been misleading, I didn't mean to propose a one-liner for it being a one-liner ;-) `fromisoformat` is more readable in my opinion and [very efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime).

Comment: I understand you didn't mean to propose one line solution. It is just that I got random dislikes for posting this solution and I can't figure out why. So, I figured it could one line people. I agree `fromisoformat` clearly is much more readable is a much better option. Thanks.

Comment: well, better not to think too much about getting downvotes. The other way around, I don't allow myself to downvote without leaving a comment. In this case, I just left the comment ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the closing quote at the end of the datetime format string, which is causing the error message you see. You also have an issue with the actual format string as well, as pointed out by @ChrisCharley

This `start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%f.%-s-%z)`

Should be `start_period_obj = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")`

To then generate your desired format you can use:

`start_period_obj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")`

See here for full details https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: The parsing string should read `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"`

Comment: Thank you for the correction on the original parsing string, I had missed that part being incorrect in the OP.