# Convert Python ISO datetime to Epoch

Tags: python, datetime

I wanted to convert the iso datetime into epoch format using python datetime library.

Below is my code, but it's not working.

```
from datetime import datetime
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
last_updated_at = int((datetime.strptime('2020-10-16T09:29:26.580-07:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f %z') - epoch).total_seconds())
```

I'm getting below error

```
ValueError: time data '2020-09-01T12:47:54.863-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f %z'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `fromisoformat` and `timestamp`:

```
from datetime import datetime

last_updated_at = int(datetime.fromisoformat('2020-10-16T09:29:26.580-07:00').timestamp()) 
# last_updated_at
# 1602865766
```

btw. your strptime format is *nearly*  correct, just a space too much. correct would have been `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'`.

Comment: @steve: it's pretty [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime), too. Just one more thing to keep in mind: when using `timestamp()`, make sure the `tzinfo` of the datetime object is set (which is the case in your example). Otherwise (naive datetime), Python will assume the date/time refers to local time - but timestamp will relate to UTC (as UNIX time is defined).