# How to convert js datetime string into python datetime object

Tags: javascript, python, html, datetime

Say I have a datetime string created form a datetime input in html as:

```
"2020-11-27T16:18"
```

How would I convert this to a datetime object in python:

```
string_date = "2020-11-27T16:18"
datetime_object = ????
```

Is there a specific way to format this date into a datetime object in python?

Comment: the format is [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how to do it using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 16, 18)
```

---

Or a more convenient and clean solution as pointed out by @MrFuppes is to use [`datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> string_date = "2020-11-27T16:18"
>>> datetime.fromisoformat(string_date)
datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 16, 18)
```

Comment: You can use `datetime.fromisoformat`, a bit more convenient

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you, that's indeed a much cleaner and reliable approach! I've incorporated it to the answer.

Comment: oh it's also pretty [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime) :) - might be a bit platform-dependent though.