# Convert date in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a data frame which is of the stop and search of the police in London; the 'date' column has entries like the `2019-10-01T04:31:39+00:00 2019-10-01T04:31:39+..` in each row I'm trying to extract day month and year to be able to begin analysis.

Could anyone please assist me in doing this??

Comment: Are all the dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" followed by timestamp?

Comment: they are actually messed up each input is like this `'2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00 2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00 2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00 2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00 2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00 2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00 2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00 2019-10-01T04....` repeating itself, I would first need to cut everything out

Comment: can you post a sample of the dataframe?  the text from df.to_dict() (or df.head(20).to_dict()`?)

Comment: Each input has a string of repeating dates n times?

Comment: I've now refresh and it isn't repeated here is a print of the the dict() of my dataframe; `'Date': {0: '2019-10-01T04:31:39+00:00',
  1: '2019-10-01T04:39:27+00:00',
  2: '2019-10-01T04:48:13+00:00',
  3: '2019-10-01T11:21:50+00:00',
  4: '2019-10-02T01:02:26+00:00',
  6: '2019-10-02T03:06:24+00:00',
  7: '2019-10-02T04:17:26+00:00',
  9: '2019-10-02T10:24:53+00:00',
  10: '2019-10-03T01:31:12+00:00',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how datetime strings are converted to date (or date time) objects in python.
For your scenario apply a function to the whole column of date strings that you reading from source.

```
def convert_str_to_date(date_string):
    converted_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    return converted_date.month, converted_date.day, converted_date.year


>>> df
         name_of_date_column
0  2019-10-01T04:31:39+00:00
1  2019-10-01T04:31:39+00:00

df.apply(lambda x: convert_str_to_date(x['name_of_date_column']), axis=1)
# 0    (10, 1, 2019)
# 1    (10, 1, 2019)
# dtype: object
```

The first line of this function is doing the work of converting string to respective elements of datetime.

Comment: note: there's [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat), see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime - but pd.to_datetime likely is more convenient here.

Comment: While that is true, the value in date-string can appear in a non-dataframe scenario as well. Hence, a more python _ish_ hack

Comment: then I'd use `datetime.fromisoformat(s).timetuple()[:3]`, giving me a y-m-d tuple

Comment: That was a learning for me. Changing few things in my code now. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[0].str.split(expand=True)
df = df.astype("datetime64").rename(columns={0:"start", 1:"end"})
df = df.astype("datetime64").rename(columns={0:"start", 1:"end"})

df[["start_day", "start_month", "start_year"]] = df.start.transform(lambda x: pd.Series([x.day, x.month, x.year]))
df[["end_day", "end_month", "end_year"]] = df.end.transform(lambda x: pd.Series([x.day, x.month, x.year]))
```

output:

```
                start                 end  start_day  start_month  start_year  end_start  end_month  end_year
0 2019-10-01 04:31:39 2019-10-01 04:31:39          1           10        2019          1         10      2019
```