# How to check datetime format in IF statement python

Tags: python, datetime

Say I have two types of datetime format need to check which are the following:

1. `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z`
2. `%Y-%m-%d`

and convert them to this format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC`.

My code at the moment only manage to check one condition :

```
if val is None:
  val2 = val
else:
  val2 = datetime.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').__format__("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
```

My pseudocode will be :

```
if val is None:
   val2 = val
elif val is in "%Y-%m-%d" format:
   do this --> val2 = convert from "%Y-%m-%d" to "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC" (eg: 2020-09-01 00:00:00 UTC)
else:
   val2 = datetime.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').__format__("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
```

The time format will be `00:00:00 UTC` constantly because there is no timestamp specified in the first place.

Comment: if `%z` in your case means e.g. `+00:00` (with the `:`), you can parse both formats with [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) - and then convert to string with strftime. that seems more readable (no conditionals) and [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13468126/10197418) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like below:

```
if val is None:
    val2 = val
elif len(val) == 10: 
    #"%Y-%m-%d" format
    val2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(val, "%Y-%m-%d").__format__("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
else:
    # Assuming only %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z format is possible. 
    # If not add if condition similar to above
    val2 = datetime.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').__format__("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC")
```

Comment: This is nice too. I just thought of this solution `val2 = val+" 00:00:00 UTC"`. Unsure if this is bad but works too. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @user6308605 Both do the same thing. You can pick what feels comfortable for you.