# Parsing string to datetime with drop milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I need to parse a string into a `datetime` with python, for example:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

But sometime I didn't know if the input is `2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860` or `2018-06-29 08:15:27` (without milliseconds).

If I tried

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-06-29 08:15:27', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I got an exception

```
ValueError: time data '2018-06-29 08:15:27' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Is there any way to use same format to `'2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860' and '2018-06-29 08:15:27'`?

I don't care about milliseconds, I want to **drop** them.

Comment: Since any inout matching your pattern has a fixed length, why not just drop any input that is too much? For example ``datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')``.

Answer (score 1):

use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) and replace microsecond with zero:

```
s = ('2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860', '2018-06-29 08:15:27')

for t in s:
    print(datetime.fromisoformat(t).replace(microsecond=0))
```

```
2018-06-29 08:15:27
2018-06-29 08:15:27
```

It's [efficient as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13468126/10197418).