# What format is this str datetime? '2021-03-16 04:00:00'

Tags: python, formatting, datetime-format

I have this DateTime which is a str and I want to convert it into a datetime obj.
What is the format?

```
2021-03-16 04:00:00
```

Right now I have:

```
format = 'yyyy-mm-dd mm:ss:ss'
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2021-03-16 04:00:00' does not match format 'yyyy-mm-dd mm:ss:ss'
```

Comment: Did you look at the [format string codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)? This is not valid format string

Comment: Your format is ISO 8601 compatible, you can simply use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat), e.g. try `datetime.fromisoformat('2021-03-16 04:00:00')`. Besides, check out https://strftime.org/ for a good overview of strptime/strftime formatting/parsing directives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. Details of the formating can be [read from the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
from datetime import datetime


date_str = "2021-03-16 04:00:00"
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_str, date_format)
print(datetime_object)
```

Output:

```
2021-03-16 04:00:00
```

**Disclaimer**

I assume that the hour is 24 hours based.

If the hour value is 12 hours based, then use `%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S`

**Reference:**

- [Strptime method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
- [Format codes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Thank you very much for including the documentation!

Comment: @svlad, you are welcome. If the answer is useful, please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: for such nicely formatted datetime strings, check out [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) - it is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime/61710371#61710371) ^^