# How to convert this string as date object in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

(Python 3.5)

I have this string:

```
2021-05-05T13:13:56+00:00
```

I want to transform it to date object to perform latter actions on it.

I've tried the following:

```
d= "2021-05-05T13:13:56+00:00"
dt = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Which trows, as expected:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00

I do not know what are exactly these elements and, refering to [this](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime), I do not find what it could refer to.

How to convert this string as a date object ?

Comment: If you don't know what your input means, you need to figure that out first.

Comment: also note: `fromisoformat` is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418).

Comment: Please see my updates Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra value is `%Z` or UTC offset, which as MrFruppes pointed out, uses a colon after Python 3.7. You can add it to your `strptime` call, or use `fromisoformat` (which is more efficient).

```
from datetime import datetime

d = "2021-05-05T13:13:56+00:00"

dt = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
dt_fromiso = datetime.fromisoformat(d)

print(dt)
print(dt_fromiso)
```

Comment: It must be added that `%z` parses a colon-separated UTC offset with Python version 3.7 onwards, see [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Please also note that for ISO format, you have [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks for educating me--I did not know that it had changed. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: no worries; the reason why I'm so picky about this is that it gives you different datetime objects depending if you set `%z` vs. `+00:00` in the parsing directive - the first sets tzinfo to timezone.utc, the second leaves it as None. That can cause unexpected behaviour later on since Python treats naive datetime (tzinfo=None) as *local time*, not UTC.

Comment: @MrFuppes I totally agree. It's much easier than manually passing a parse string to begin with, and now provides a more efficient solution

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am working with python 3.5.2, so I am not impacted. :)

Comment: @chemicalwill You may edit your answer to indicate the actual required code for <3.7

Comment: @FlorianCastelain I will do that :)