# Python convert timestamp to unix

Tags: python, datetime, unix, utc

I know these questions have been asked before but I'm struggling to convert a timestamp string to a unix time and figuring out whether the datetime objects are naive or aware

For example, to convert the time "2021-05-19 12:51:47" to unix:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> dt_obj = dt.strptime("2021-05-19 12:51:47", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> dt_obj
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 19, 12, 51, 47)
```

is `dt_obj` naive or aware and how would you determine this? The methods on dt_obj such as `timetz`, `tzinfo`, and `tzname` don't seem to indicate anything - does that mean that dt_obj is naive?

Then to get unix:

```
>>> dt_obj.timestamp()
1621421507.0
```

However when I check `1621421507.0` on say https://www.unixtimestamp.com then it tells me that gmt for the above is Wed May 19 2021 10:51:47 GMT+0000, ie 2 hours behind the original timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since Python's datetime treats naive datetime as *local time* by default, you need to set the time zone (`tzinfo` attribute):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# assuming "2021-05-19 12:51:47" represents UTC:
dt_obj = datetime.fromisoformat("2021-05-19 12:51:47").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Or, as @Wolf suggested, instead of setting the tzinfo attribute explicitly, you can also modify the input string by adding `"+00:00"` which is parsed to UTC;

```
dt_obj = datetime.fromisoformat("2021-05-19 12:51:47" + "+00:00")
```

In any case, the result

```
dt_obj.timestamp()
# 1621428707.0
```

now converts as expected on https://www.unixtimestamp.com/:
[image]

Comment: What speaks against `datetime.fromisoformat("2021-05-19 12:51:47 +00:00")`?

Comment: Thank you so much and noted on `datetime.fromisoformat`

Comment: @Wolf: I've added your suggestion to the answer, thanks for the comment! I was a bit reluctant to the string modification but it's clearly more efficient than using `replace`.

Comment: @MrFuppes Well, it adds to the input (`input+' +00:00'`), but doesn't your first solution modify the datetime object? Isn't this biased within one hour in a year, specifically between `2021-10-31 02:00:00 +02:00` and `2021-10-31 02:00:00 +01:00`?

Comment: @uroboros: glad I could help! also take note of Wolf's suggestion; it's more efficient if you have a lot of data to process.

Comment: @Wolf regarding *"Isn't this biased within one hour in a year"*: you mean because of a DST transition? - No I don't think so, assuming the input string represents UTC. If it would represent local time, then yes. You'd have to set the local time zone first and *then* convert to UTC (and then take timestamp if needed).

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't specify the timezone when calling `strptime`, you will produce *naive* `datetime` objects. You may pass time zone information via `%z` format specifier and `+00:00` added to the textual date-time representation to get a timezone *aware* `datetime` object:

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt_str = "2021-05-19 12:51:47"
print(dt_str)
dt_obj = datetime.strptime(dt_str+"+00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
print(dt_obj)
print(dt_obj.timestamp())
```

The of above script is this:

```
2021-05-19 12:51:47
2021-05-19 12:51:47+00:00
1621428707.0
```

Comment: speaking of efficiency, note: [A faster strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13468126/10197418)

Answer (score 1):

[`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

> Naive datetime instances are assumed to represent local time and this method relies on the platform C mktime() function to perform the conversion.

So using this does automatically apply yours machine current timezone, following recipe is given to calculate timestamp from naive datetime without influence of timezone:

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: although this is also suggested elsewhere, I think it is hard to read and only works because `datetime(1970, 1, 1)` is also treated as local time. To me, this seems like "right for the wrong reason".