# ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.6

I am having some problem converting this datetime format: **2021-08-12T09:15:17+02:00** from string to datetime.

The piece of code I'm using to convert it is the following:

```
value = datetime.strptime('2021-08-12T09:15:17+02:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Everything seems to work correctly if the python version used is **3.8**, while if the version is **3.6** I get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2021-08-12T09:15:17+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

How can I solve?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Python 3.6 doesn't support the colon `:` in the UTC offset yet, was added with Python 3.7. You can remove it e.g. like `'2021-08-12T09:15:17+02:00'[::-1].replace(":", "", 1)[::-1]`.

Comment: Ok thank you, at the moment the only alternative I found is to use the parser module of the dateutil package. `parser.parse('2021-08-12T09:15:17+02:00')`, your solution works fine too

Comment: if performance + 3rd party libs are not an issue, I'm with you, dateutil's parser is a convenient alternative. Btw. with Python 3.8, datetime.fromisoformat should do an even better job, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710371/10197418) ;-)