# converting json timestamp to datetime in python

Tags: python, json, datetime

How can I convert '2021-11-21T18:57:18.000+01:00' from json to datetime in Python?

```
  timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

is giving me error:

> ValueError: time data '2021-11-21T18:57:18.000+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

Comment: Python 3.7+: use [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat), it is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13468126/10197418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting string is slightly wrong. You need `%z` to parse the zone offset:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = '2021-11-21T18:57:18.000+01:00'
timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")

print(timestamp)
```

Result:

```
2021-11-21 18:57:18+01:00
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! Really appreciate it